# Mac iPhone Simulator running very slowly when Core Location tracking is enabled

Tags: iphone, performance, ios-simulator

I have an iPhone program using Core Location.

When I run it on the *simulator* - the simulator seems to run very slowly. By this - I mean mouse movements are very slow and jerky.

I can see no noticable difference however in CPU utilization, network or disk activity, etc (on the simulator or the Mac itself). This problem *only* happens when Core Location is enabled, and requesting location update events.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to avoid it? It is a Core Location problem on the iPhone? The Simulator? The Macintosh?

Answer (score 0):

What's your XCode version ? It may be a simulator problem.

Did you try on device ?

Sometimes the SDK (most of the time during beta), has difficulties. So it can be very slow on simulator ^^

Good Luck

Comment: It's the last major release - no betas or anything. It all runs fine on the device. Makes little sense - looks almost like a Mac Core Location problem - because of the way it affects the mouse movement on the Mac.